# How to specify Glue Table and schema in Glue crawler using cloud formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I'm creating Glue Database, Glue Table with Schema, and Glue Crawler using CFT, please find my code below. In my Glue Crawler, I would like to specify the glue table "`myTestTable`" and `schema` in the Glue Crawler so that when any schema update happens (adding or removing any field) my crawler automatically updates with this new schema change.

How can I achieve this using CFT, it would be really appreciated if someone can help me to resolve this issue.

```
  GlueDatabase:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Database
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseInput:
        Name: myTestGlueDB

  GlueTable:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabase
      TableInput:
        Parameters:
          classification: parquet
        Name: myTestTable
        Owner: owner
        Retention: 0
        StorageDescriptor:
          Columns:
          - Name: productName
            Type: string
          - Name: productId
            Type: string
          InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat
          OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
          Compressed: false
          NumberOfBuckets: -1
          SerdeInfo:
            SerializationLibrary: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe
            Parameters:
              serialization.format: '1'
          Location: s3://test-bucket
          BucketColumns: []
          SortColumns: []
          StoredAsSubDirectories: false
        PartitionKeys:
        - Name: id
          Type: string
        - Name: year
          Type: string
        - Name: month
          Type: string
        - Name: day
          Type: string
        TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE

  GlueCrawler:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      Name: myTestCrawler
      Role: GlueCrawlerRole
      DatabaseName: myTestGlueDB
      TablePrefix: myTable-
      Targets:
        S3Targets:
          - Path: s3://test-bucket
      SchemaChangePolicy:
        UpdateBehavior: UPDATE_IN_DATABASE
        DeleteBehavior: LOG 
      Configuration: "{\"Version\":1.0,\"Grouping\":{\"TableGroupingPolicy\":\"CombineCompatibleSchemas\"}}"
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current template? ANy errors or why it does not work?

Comment: No error in my current template, this template creates a Glue table with my predefined schema, and when the crawler run it create another table with dynamic schema (based on S3 data), for example very first time table create with productid, productname, id, month, year and day - when crawler creates the table and if s3 data doesn't have product name then crawler create the table using s3 data and schema is getting updated. I would like to avoid that - regardless of all fields exist or not in my s3 - my table should contain all schema.

Comment: So don't run the crawler. I'm not sure why would use use it, if you have pre-defined schema?

Comment: For adding partitions maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to define a `CatalogTarget` instead of a `S3Target`. So replace following in your Crawler config:

```
Targets:
        S3Targets:
          - Path: s3://test-bucket
```

with:

```
  Targets:
    CatalogTargets:
        - DatabaseName: !Ref GlueDatabase
          Tables:
            - !Ref GlueTable
```

Additional resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/tables-described.html#update-manual-tables
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-crawler-catalogtarget.html

Note that when using CatalogTargets you can't do incremental crawls. You will need to use the `CRAWL_EVERYTHING` option as RecrawlBehavior. This may impact the runtime of your crawler, but this will by default update your schema.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-configure-changes-console